# Detecting Media-Button press in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, events

How can I detect a mediabutton press (on earbuds,selfie-sticks,..) in react-native?

I have tried numerous libraries and solutions, they all failed. The closest solution I got is from a library called [react-native-incall-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-incall-manager).
This was originally made to give more control during calls, but they also bring the option to detect certain events. Some of these events work, like detecting if the audiojack is plugged in or out. The one I need, the mediabutton event, doesn't work. The physical button works, just not with my application I'm developing.

This works:

```
import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native'

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('WiredHeadset', function (data) {
        console.log('detected');
    });
```

This doesn't:

```
import InCallManager from 'react-native-incall-manager';
import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native'

DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('MediaButton', function (data) {
        console.log('button pressed');
    });
```

If there is an obvious solution I am missing, I would love to hear it.

Comment: Which platform is 'MediaButton' not working for? The react-native-incall-manager README says that 'WiredHeadSet' should work for iOS and Android, but that 'MediaButton' is only available for Android.

Comment: It's for android. I am now trying to create my own module in in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.
This library fixed it: https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent

It only works on android for now.

Comment: iOS is partially added to that library